# Amazon Polly acronyms and sentence ends

Tags: text-to-speech, amazon-polly

Try this simple sentence on Polly console.

**This is IME. We should go now.**

Since IME is not a common acronym, it is incorrectly read. So, I replaced it with

**This is I.M.E. We should go now.**

As expected, IME is now correctly read. However, the sentence-ending period is now ignored. What's the solution to this problem?